# .NetFramework 4 SDK

Tags: .net

Where can I download .NetFramework 4 SDK?

**Update**
I am looking specifically for the SDK and tools that come with it like GacUtil, not just the .NetFramework 4 Redistributable which lacks these tools.

I want to avoid installing VS 2010 if possible...

**Answer from below**

Windows SDK that includes .NET 4.0, it was not announced or released yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en) is a link to the web installer for .NET 4.0.

If you are looking for the Windows SDK that includes .NET 4.0, it was not announced or released yet. Once it is, you will be able to find in on the [Windows SDK Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx).

Comment: Ok, so it is not out yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get just the Framework/SDK here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also download Visual C# Express 2010 for free and get an IDE in the process.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS